# Data Factory - pass json to foreach activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

In DataFactory, I'm creating a ForEach activity and in Items I'm using this expression:

[image]

```
    @createArray(json('{
    "daily": {
        "raw": [
            {
                "entity_name": "ent1",
                "fetchXML_file": "raw/ent1.xml",
                "destination_path_base": "/master/raw/ent1"
            },
            {
                "entity_name": "ent2",
                "fetchXML_file": "raw/ent2.xml",
                "destination_path_base": "/master/raw/ent2"
            },
            {
                "entity_name": "ent3",
                "fetchXML_file": "raw/ent3.xml",
                "destination_path_base": "/master/raw/ent3"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'))
```

and I want to use fetchXML_file values but it doesn't work.

If I put this: `@item().daily.raw[0].fetchXML_file` it will work just for ent1, but I want to use all the values (ent1, ent2 and ent3)

I wanted to achieve this method, because it is "cleaner" than creating parameters and then modifying the json or adding more things to the json.

Can anyone help to achieve this ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass items to For Each activity It should be in array format. your `create Array` and `Json` function converting object to array and it not iterating over the **raw**- array.

**To achieve this follow below steps:**

1. First take foreach activity with items as your expression.
   [image]

- Under for each loop take a Set variable activity and create an `Array type` variable to **store the raw array** with  value `@item().daily.raw`
  [image]
  **Output of it:**
  [image]

2. Then take another for each activity to iterate over this array now. in items pass `@variables('demo')`
   [image]

- Now under this foreach you will be able to iterate over the raw array and extract value oof each
  **fetchXML_file**
  [image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Great answer, for me it worked!!